# CheckBox not retaining Checked value on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, user-controls, postback

I have two CheckBox controls that do not keep their Checked value on the first PostBack, but on the second they keep their value. I have been trying to figure out why they do not keep their value.

In my debugging process, I have found that they lose their checked value by the time the first line in the master page `Page_Load()` function is executed after there is a button clicked. The call back function for the button is in the custom user control.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this

Comment: Are these checkboxes programatically created? If not, then is viewstate enabled?

Comment: No, not programatically and ViewState is enabled on them and i could not find anywhere in the control or the master page that disables view state.

Comment: This issue may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38708500/2415524