# ASP.NET CheckBox not checked on postback without weird hack

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, postback

I have a `GridView` with a checkbox column. On clicking a button, all rows with the checkbox checked should be removed. I somehow stumbled upon a strange and hacky solution, and I have no idea why it works. I already searched through related SO questions already.

Related code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    ' I have no idea why this is needed for the checkboxes to work...
    Dim x = imageGridView.Rows
End Sub


Protected Sub RemoveButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles removeButton.Click

    For Each row As GridViewRow In imageGridView.Rows
        Dim selectCheckBox As CheckBox = DirectCast(row.Cells(0).FindControl("selectCheckBox"), CheckBox)
        If selectCheckBox.Checked Then
            Dim fileName As String = row.Cells(1).Text
            ImageList.Remove(ImageList.FindLast(Function(r) r.FileName = fileName))
        End If
    Next
    imageGridView.DataSource = ImageList
    imageGridView.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="imageGridView" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="selectCheckBox" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The line `Dim x = imageGridView.Rows` is needed for the rows to be removed. I found this after trying my `RemoveButton_Click` code in the `Page_Init` sub, then removing code until it didn't work anymore. `Dim x = imageGridView` is not enough, and it doesn't work to do the same thing in `Page_Load`.

My checkboxes are never disabled.

So, simply put, why is it necessary for me to reference `imageGridView.Rows` in the `Page_Init` for my code to work?

Comment: Are you doing a full postback, or using update panels?

Comment: I have an `UpdatePanel` that the `addButton` triggers, but the grid is not contained within the panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an interesting behavior. I reproduce the problem if I bind the data to the GridView in `Page_Load` on every postback. In that situation, the check boxes lose their selection state on postback, but not if we refer to `imageGridView.Rows` in `Page_Init`, as you observed.

The solution is to bind the data inside an `If Not IsPostBack` conditional block:

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        imageGridView.DataSource = ImageList
        imageGridView.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

In that case, however, we must NOT refer to `imageGridView.Rows` in `Page_Init`. Doing so causes the check boxes to lose their selection state (!?!).

From the source code of the GridView (assuming that [this source](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/UI/WebControls/GridView@cs/1546361/GridView@cs) is reliable), I notice that accessing the `Rows` collection triggers a call to `EnsureChildControls` which then calls `CreateChildControls`. I haven't been able to step into the .NET code to see what happens at that point. Calling these methods in the `Page_Init` event handler may come earlier than expected in the [life cycle of the GridView](http://thesitedoctor.co.uk/blog/complete-lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-page-and-controls/).

By the way, accessing the `HeaderRow` and the `FooterRow` properties also triggers a call to `EnsureChildControls`, and has the same effect on the selection status of the check boxes.

Comment: I thought I had to rebind the data every postback or it wouldn't carry over, but apparently not. Thanks!